# gitlab_rails['backup_path'] ignored

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I want to change the default location of gitlab's backups.

However the following procedure does not work and backups still go to the default location (`/var/opt/gitlab/backups`):

1. change `gitlab_rails['backup_path']` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`to

   ```
   gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = "/home/Shared/gitlab-backups"
   ```
2. run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
3. run again `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create`